# Stamen terrain map not working in Cartopy

Tags: python, matplotlib, gis, cartopy, stamen-maps

I am using Cartopy (v0.21.1) to make an inset map in matplotlib (v3.7.1) with cartopy.io.img_tiles.Stamen('terrain-background'). This method worked seamlessly up until about a week ago.

Now I get this error that only occurs sometimes:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/envs/xuscd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
    339                 pass
    340             else:
--> 341                 return printer(obj)
    342             # Finally look for special method names
    343             method = get_real_method(obj, self.print_method)

~/anaconda3/envs/xuscd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/pylabtools.py in <lambda>(fig)
    246 
    247     if 'png' in formats:
--> 248         png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: print_figure(fig, 'png', **kwargs))
    249     if 'retina' in formats or 'png2x' in formats:
    250         png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: retina_figure(fig, **kwargs))

~/anaconda3/envs/xuscd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/pylabtools.py in print_figure(fig, fmt, bbox_inches, **kwargs)
    130         FigureCanvasBase(fig)
    131 
--> 132     fig.canvas.print_figure(bytes_io, **kw)
    133     data = bytes_io.getvalue()
    134     if fmt == 'svg':

~/anaconda3/envs/xuscd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py in print_figure(self, filename, dpi, facecolor, edgecolor, orientation, format, bbox_inches, pad_inches, bbox_extra_artists, backend, **kwargs)
   2340                 )
   2341                 with getattr(renderer, "_draw_disabled", nullcontext)():
-> 2342                     self.figure.draw(renderer)
   2343 
   2344             if bbox_inches:

~/anaconda3/envs/xuscd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     93     @wraps(draw)
     94     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
---> 95         result = draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     96         if renderer._rasterizing:
     97             renderer.stop_rasterizing()

~/anaconda3/envs/xuscd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer)
     70                 renderer.start_filter()
     71 
---> 72             return draw(artist, renderer)
     73         finally:
     74             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:

~/anaconda3/envs/xuscd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py in draw(self, renderer)
   3138 
   3139             self.patch.draw(renderer)
-> 3140             mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(
   3141                 renderer, self, artists, self.suppressComposite)
   3142 

~/anaconda3/envs/xuscd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py in _draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, parent, artists, suppress_composite)
    129     if not_composite or not has_images:
    130         for a in artists:
--> 131             a.draw(renderer)
    132     else:
    133         # Composite any adjacent images together

~/anaconda3/envs/xuscd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer)
     70                 renderer.start_filter()
     71 
---> 72             return draw(artist, renderer)
     73         finally:
     74             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:

~/anaconda3/envs/xuscd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cartopy/mpl/geoaxes.py in draw(self, renderer, **kwargs)
    529         if not self._done_img_factory:
    530             for factory, factory_args, factory_kwargs in self.img_factories:
--> 531                 img, extent, origin = factory.image_for_domain(
    532                     self._get_extent_geom(factory.crs), factory_args[0])
    533                 self.imshow(img, extent=extent, origin=origin,

~/anaconda3/envs/xuscd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cartopy/io/img_tiles.py in image_for_domain(self, target_domain, target_z)
     97 
     98         print(f'img shape = {img.shape}')
---> 99         img, extent, origin = _merge_tiles(tiles)
    100         return img, extent, origin
    101 

~/anaconda3/envs/xuscd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cartopy/io/img_tiles.py in _merge_tiles(tiles)
    652         print(img_slice)
    653 
--> 654         img[img_slice] = tile_img
    655 
    656     return img, [min(xs), max(xs), min(ys), max(ys)], 'lower'

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (512,512,3) into shape (766,766,3)
```

Did the Stamen map update? Could this be breaking the existing Cartopy code by modifying the size of the map image?

Answer (score 2):

Stamen stopped providing a base map service last week - this was [announced some time ago](https://stamen.com/here-comes-the-future-of-stamen-maps/), their maps are now provided by [Stadia](https://stadiamaps.com/stamen/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had not seen that until now. Turns out it has an effect on Cartopy's Stamen mapping features that are unable to be resolved for now.

Comment: I stumbled upon the same issue today. If you find out any workaround I would be grateful if you share it.

Answer (score 1):

As described in other answers, Stamen has stopped providing a base map service.
As a workaround to continue using your Cartopy code (almost) as-is:

1. Create a free account (200k credits/month) and get an API key from Stadia Maps here: https://stadiamaps.com/stamen/onboarding/create-account/
2. Override the Cartopy Stamen map class as follows, using your API key:

```py
import cartopy.io.img_tiles as cimgt

class StadiaStamen(cimgt.Stamen):
    def _image_url(self, tile):
         x,y,z = tile
         url = f"https://tiles.stadiamaps.com/tiles/stamen_terrain_background/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?api_key={API_KEY}"
         return url
```

3. Replace calls to the old Stamen class with the new class, e.g.

```py
stamen_terrain = StadiaStamen("terrain-background")
```