# Mapbox satellite map in cartopy throws new error one week later

Tags: python, mapbox, cartopy

I'm having a very similar problem to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77248120/stamen-terrain-map-not-working-in-cartopy), but working with Mapbox's satellite maps. The code ran no problem last week, now getting `ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (512,512,3) into shape (766,512,3)`

Here is the code:

```
import cartopy.io.img_tiles as cimgt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mapbox = cimgt.MapboxTiles(access_token=token, map_id = 'satellite-v9')

ax = plt.axes(projection=mapbox.crs)
ax.set_extent(extent)
ax.add_image(mapbox, 14)
plt.show()
```

and that throws this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/<ENV>/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 1226, in _on_timer
    ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/<ENV>/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_macosx.py", line 68, in callback_func
    callback()
  File "/<ENV>/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_macosx.py", line 88, in _draw_idle
    self.draw()
  File "/<ENV>/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_macosx.py", line 50, in draw
    super().draw()
  File "/<ENV>/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 400, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "/<ENV>/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 95, in draw_wrapper
    result = draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/<ENV>/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 72, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer)
  File "/<ENV>/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 3140, in draw
    mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(
  File "/<ENV>/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 131, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "/<ENV>/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 72, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer)
  File "/<ENV>/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cartopy/mpl/geoaxes.py", line 528, in draw
    img, extent, origin = factory.image_for_domain(
  File "/<ENV>/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cartopy/io/img_tiles.py", line 98, in image_for_domain
    img, extent, origin = _merge_tiles(tiles)
  File "/<ENV>/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cartopy/io/img_tiles.py", line 669, in _merge_tiles
    img[img_slice] = tile_img
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (512,512,3) into shape (512,766,3)
```

Was there an update that would have broken this? I'd love to continue using Mapbox.

Comment: Can you include what `extent` you used?  I tried adding one but the plot just hung.  I do not know whether this is a symptom of the same problem or because I chose a too large extent.

Comment: @RuthC 
`north = 21.05,
south = 20.55,
east = -155.95,
west = -156.75,
extent=[west,east,south,north]`
Are you having similar problems?

Comment: I just tried your script with those extents.  It took a while to render but I got a plot.  I wonder if you hit some kind of temporary server problem.  Have you tried again?